# AS3 dialog still present after removeChild and more efforts to make it go away

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

This is another very weird problem, it's a dialog in a play flow that's supposed to disappear after the player makes a choice with one of its buttons, but it's not disappearing no matter what I try.

What is particularly odd is that none of the associated code has changed in at least 18 months, including where it's called from, and it was working fine until a couple days ago with commits that all had to do with the ship objects, not the dialogs.

And there is one and only one place this dialog is called from - one of the first things I wondered is whether I was getting multiple instances of this dialog being created somehow but no, not that I see.

[image: Player has selected one of his ships and clicked on a valid enemy target, all combat calculations done and Broadside Confirm dialog instanced, all we need to know is whether player wants to shoot at rigging or the hull.]

When the player clicks on one of the fire buttons we calculate the combat results and display them both in the broadside results screen but also on the enemy ship's info screen. If the player cancels, we're supposed to clear the screen.

On the broadside results dialog, we just have the Close button, which calls the same function as the broadside confirm dialog cancel button to clear the screen.

Here is the Broadside Results Dialog view, player has hit one of the fire buttons, damage calculated and applied. At this point the Broadside Confirm dialog is supposed to already be gone, but it's not- it's hiding under the results dialog.

[Broadside Results Phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Kl3.jpg)

Here's the first version of that "clear map" code which worked fine until a few days ago:

```
//clears game map of dialogs and resets ships to deselected states, called from several places
        function clearGameMap(eventTarget:Object) {

            //clear selected state on all ships, remove ship info screen, broadside confirm and broadside results dialogs
            for (var i: int = 0; i < shipListSide1.length; i++) {

                //clear all selected states and return to default unselected background graphic
                shipListSide1[i].selected = false;
                shipListSide1[i].combatSelected = false;

                //selection borders
                var borderChild = shipListSide1[i].getChildByName("shipBorder");
                borderChild.visible = false;

                var borderChildCombat = shipListSide1[i].getChildByName("borderCombat");
                borderChildCombat.visible = false;

                //show default counter background, build label name, leave surrendered ships to sleep peacefully
                if (!shipListSide1[i].isSurrendered) {

                    shipListSide1[i].gotoAndStop(shipListSide1[i].country+"_def");
                }
            }

            //clear selected states side2
            for (var i: int = 0; i < shipListSide2.length; i++) {

                //clear all selected states and return to default unselected background graphic
                shipListSide2[i].selected = false;
                shipListSide2[i].combatSelected = false;

                //selection borders
                var borderChild = shipListSide2[i].getChildByName("shipBorder");
                borderChild.visible = false;

                var borderChildCombat2 = shipListSide2[i].getChildByName("borderCombat");
                borderChildCombat2.visible = false;

                //show default counter background, build label name, leave surrendered ships to sleep peacefully
                if (!shipListSide2[i].isSurrendered) {

                    shipListSide2[i].gotoAndStop(shipListSide2[i].country+"_def");
                }

            }

            //in this one case we're transitioning from broadside confirm dialog to broadside results dialog and we DON'T want to remove the info screens
            if (("broadsideFireButtonHull" != eventTarget.name) && ("broadsideFireButtonRigging" != eventTarget.name)) {

                //remove ship info screen
                if (currShipInfo.parent) {

                    removeChild(currShipInfo);
                }
                //remove ship target info screen
                if (currShipInfo_combat.parent) {

                    removeChild(currShipInfo_combat);
                }
            }

            //remove broadside confirm dialog
            if (broadsideConfirmDialog.parent) {

                removeChild(broadsideConfirmDialog);

            }
            //remove broadside results dialog
            if (broadsideResultsDialog.parent) {

                removeChild(broadsideResultsDialog);
            }
        }
```

However it stopped working, this is what I get now:

[image: Everything is cleared except the Broadside Confirm Dialog, which already should have disappeared when we went to Broadside Results. Ship names are gone but all other children still present and event listeners on buttons still functional]

I check the variable at that point and indeed its parent is now null, but it's still being displayed on screen. Or at least I don't see another instance.

So I made some efforts to make it go away:

```
                //remove broadside confirm dialog
            if (broadsideConfirmDialog.parent) {

                broadsideConfirmDialog.parent.setChildIndex(broadsideConfirmDialog, broadsideConfirmDialog.parent.getChildIndex(broadsideConfirmDialog) - 1);
                broadsideConfirmDialog.visible = false;
                broadsideConfirmDialog.alpha = 0;

                var fireHullButton = broadsideConfirmDialog.getChildByName("broadsideFireButtonHull");
                var fireRiggingButton = broadsideConfirmDialog.getChildByName("broadsideFireButtonRigging");
                var broadside_CancelButton = broadsideConfirmDialog.getChildByName("broadsideCancelButton");

                fireHullButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireButtonHandler);
                fireHullButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, broadsideButtonRollOverHandler);
                fireHullButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, broadsideButtonRollOutHandler);

                fireRiggingButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireButtonHandler);
                fireRiggingButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, broadsideButtonRollOverHandler);
                fireRiggingButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, broadsideButtonRollOutHandler);

                broadside_CancelButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cancelButtonHandler);
                broadside_CancelButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, broadsideButtonRollOverHandler);
                broadside_CancelButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, broadsideButtonRollOutHandler);

                removeChild(broadsideConfirmDialog);

            }
```

Removed event listeners, tried to push it back in z order, invisible, alpha 0, but none of it works, it is a terminator dialog. But ALL of this code executes with zero errors. Again, I don't see another instance and I also don't see how a second instance could exist, but those damned buttons are still doing their rollovers after I supposedly successfully removed the required event listener.

Here is the code that creates the Broadside Confirm and Broadside Results dialogs and the event listeners/handlers, none of which has changed in many months. The results dialog goes away with no issues when told to:

```
function createBroadsideConfirmDialog(firingShip, targetShip, initialHitTable, hitTable, modSternRake, modRakeValue, modCrewQuality, modInitialBroadside, modShotType, modAnchored, modCrewLosses, finalGuns, targetRange) {

            //only display if ship can fire to this side
            if ((targetObj.targetStarboard && targetObj.firingShip.loadedRight) || (false == targetObj.targetStarboard && targetObj.firingShip.loadedLeft)) {

                broadsideConfirmDialog = new Broadside_Confirm_Dialog();

                broadsideConfirmDialog.x = 430;
                broadsideConfirmDialog.y = 117;

                addChild(broadsideConfirmDialog);

                //firing and target ship name fields
                var broadsideShipNameFont = new ShipNameFont();

                var textBroadsideShipNameFormat: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                textBroadsideShipNameFormat.size = 16;
                textBroadsideShipNameFormat.font = broadsideShipNameFont.fontName;

                textBroadsideShipNameFire.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideShipNameFormat;

                textBroadsideShipNameFire.width = 200;
                textBroadsideShipNameFire.height = 16;
                textBroadsideShipNameFire.x = 55;
                textBroadsideShipNameFire.y = 15;
                textBroadsideShipNameFire.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideShipNameFire.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                textBroadsideShipNameFire.htmlText = "<p align='center'>" + firingShip.name + "</p>";

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideShipNameFire);

                textBroadsideShipNameTarget.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideShipNameFormat;

                textBroadsideShipNameTarget.width = 200;
                textBroadsideShipNameTarget.height = 16;
                textBroadsideShipNameTarget.x = 55;
                textBroadsideShipNameTarget.y = 71;
                textBroadsideShipNameTarget.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideShipNameTarget.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                textBroadsideShipNameTarget.htmlText = "<p align='center'>" + targetShip.name + "</p>";

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideShipNameTarget);

                //gun and range fields
                var broadsideConfirmFields = new Arial();

                var textBroadsideGunsFormat: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                textBroadsideGunsFormat.size = 16;
                textBroadsideGunsFormat.font = broadsideConfirmFields.fontName;

                var textBroadsideGuns: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideGuns.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideGunsFormat;

                textBroadsideGuns.width = 80;
                textBroadsideGuns.height = 30;
                textBroadsideGuns.x = 167;
                textBroadsideGuns.y = 186;
                textBroadsideGuns.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideGuns.textColor = 0xFFCC00;

                textBroadsideGuns.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + finalGuns + "</p>";

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideGuns);

                var textBroadsideRange: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideRange.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideGunsFormat;

                textBroadsideRange.width = 80;
                textBroadsideRange.height = 30;
                textBroadsideRange.x = 67;
                textBroadsideRange.y = 186;
                textBroadsideRange.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideRange.textColor = 0xFFCC00;

                textBroadsideRange.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + targetRange + "</p>";

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideRange);

                //initial and final hit table fields
                textBroadsideHitTableFormat.size = 22;
                textBroadsideHitTableFormat.font = broadsideConfirmFields.fontName;

                var textBroadsideHitTable: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideHitTable.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideHitTableFormat;

                textBroadsideHitTable.width = 80;
                textBroadsideHitTable.height = 30;
                textBroadsideHitTable.x = 235;
                textBroadsideHitTable.y = 185;
                textBroadsideHitTable.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideHitTable.textColor = 0xFFCC00;

                textBroadsideHitTable.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + initialHitTable + "</p>";

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideHitTable);

                var textBroadsideFinalHitTable: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideFinalHitTable.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideHitTableFormat;

                textBroadsideFinalHitTable.name = "textBroadsideFinalHitTable";
                textBroadsideFinalHitTable.width = 80;
                textBroadsideFinalHitTable.height = 30;
                textBroadsideFinalHitTable.x = 235;
                textBroadsideFinalHitTable.y = 325;
                textBroadsideFinalHitTable.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideFinalHitTable.textColor = 0xFFCC00;

                textBroadsideFinalHitTable.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + hitTable + "</p>";

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideFinalHitTable);

                //modifier fields
                var textBroadsideModifiersFormat: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                textBroadsideModifiersFormat.size = 13;
                textBroadsideModifiersFormat.font = broadsideConfirmFields.fontName;

                var textBroadsideModCrew: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideModCrew.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideModifiersFormat;

                textBroadsideModCrew.width = 80;
                textBroadsideModCrew.height = 30;
                textBroadsideModCrew.x = 232;
                textBroadsideModCrew.y = 214;
                textBroadsideModCrew.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideModCrew.textColor = 0xFFDD8C;

                textBroadsideModCrew.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + modCrewQuality + "</p>";

                if ("0" == modCrewQuality) {
                    textBroadsideModCrew.htmlText = "<p align='left'>--</p>";
                    textBroadsideModCrew.x = 238;
                    textBroadsideModCrew.textColor = 0x999999;
                }

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideModCrew);

                var textBroadsideModAmmo: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideModAmmo.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideModifiersFormat;

                textBroadsideModAmmo.width = 80;
                textBroadsideModAmmo.height = 30;
                textBroadsideModAmmo.x = 232;
                textBroadsideModAmmo.y = 233;
                textBroadsideModAmmo.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideModAmmo.textColor = 0xFFDD8C;

                textBroadsideModAmmo.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + modShotType + "</p>";

                if ("0" == modShotType) {
                    textBroadsideModAmmo.htmlText = "<p align='left'>--</p>";
                    textBroadsideModAmmo.x = 238;
                    textBroadsideModAmmo.textColor = 0x999999;
                }

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideModAmmo);

                var textBroadsideModRake: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideModRake.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideModifiersFormat;

                textBroadsideModRake.width = 80;
                textBroadsideModRake.height = 30;
                textBroadsideModRake.x = 232;
                textBroadsideModRake.y = 251;
                textBroadsideModRake.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideModRake.textColor = 0xFFDD8C;

                textBroadsideModRake.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + modRakeValue + "</p>";

                if ("0" == modRakeValue) {
                    textBroadsideModRake.htmlText = "<p align='left'>--</p>";
                    textBroadsideModRake.x = 238;
                    textBroadsideModRake.y = 249;
                    textBroadsideModRake.textColor = 0x999999;
                }

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideModRake);

                var textBroadsideModSternRake: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideModSternRake.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideModifiersFormat;

                textBroadsideModSternRake.width = 80;
                textBroadsideModSternRake.height = 30;
                textBroadsideModSternRake.x = 232;
                textBroadsideModSternRake.y = 269;
                textBroadsideModSternRake.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideModSternRake.textColor = 0xFFDD8C;

                textBroadsideModSternRake.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + modSternRake + "</p>";

                if ("0" == modSternRake) {
                    textBroadsideModSternRake.htmlText = "<p align='left'>--</p>";
                    textBroadsideModSternRake.x = 238;
                    textBroadsideModSternRake.y = 267;
                    textBroadsideModSternRake.textColor = 0x999999;
                }

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideModSternRake);

                var textBroadsideModInitBroad: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideModInitBroad.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideModifiersFormat;

                textBroadsideModInitBroad.width = 80;
                textBroadsideModInitBroad.height = 30;
                textBroadsideModInitBroad.x = 232;
                textBroadsideModInitBroad.y = 287;
                textBroadsideModInitBroad.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideModInitBroad.textColor = 0xFFDD8C;

                textBroadsideModInitBroad.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + modInitialBroadside + "</p>";

                if ("0" == modInitialBroadside) {
                    textBroadsideModInitBroad.htmlText = "<p align='left'>--</p>";
                    textBroadsideModInitBroad.x = 238;
                    textBroadsideModInitBroad.y = 285;
                    textBroadsideModInitBroad.textColor = 0x999999;
                }

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideModInitBroad);

                var textBroadsideModCrewLosses: TextField = new TextField();
                textBroadsideModCrewLosses.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideModifiersFormat;

                textBroadsideModCrewLosses.width = 80;
                textBroadsideModCrewLosses.height = 30;
                textBroadsideModCrewLosses.x = 234;
                textBroadsideModCrewLosses.y = 304;
                textBroadsideModCrewLosses.embedFonts = true;
                textBroadsideModCrewLosses.textColor = 0xFFDD8C;

                textBroadsideModCrewLosses.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + modCrewLosses + "</p>";

                if ("0" == modCrewLosses) {
                    textBroadsideModCrewLosses.htmlText = "<p align='left'>--</p>";
                    textBroadsideModCrewLosses.x = 238;
                    textBroadsideModCrewLosses.y = 303;
                    textBroadsideModCrewLosses.textColor = 0x999999;
                }

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(textBroadsideModCrewLosses);

                //fire and cancel buttons
                var broadsideFireButtonHull: Broadside_Confirm_Btn_Fire_Hull = new Broadside_Confirm_Btn_Fire_Hull();
                broadsideFireButtonHull.gotoAndStop('default');

                broadsideFireButtonHull.x = 208;
                broadsideFireButtonHull.y = 372;

                broadsideFireButtonHull.name = "broadsideFireButtonHull";
                broadsideFireButtonHull.buttonMode = true;
                broadsideFireButtonHull.useHandCursor = true;
                broadsideFireButtonHull.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireButtonHandler);
                broadsideFireButtonHull.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, broadsideButtonRollOverHandler);
                broadsideFireButtonHull.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, broadsideButtonRollOutHandler);

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(broadsideFireButtonHull);

                var broadsideFireButtonRigging: Broadside_Confirm_Btn_Fire_Rigging = new Broadside_Confirm_Btn_Fire_Rigging();
                broadsideFireButtonRigging.gotoAndStop('default');

                broadsideFireButtonRigging.x = 99;
                broadsideFireButtonRigging.y = 372;

                broadsideFireButtonRigging.name = "broadsideFireButtonRigging";
                broadsideFireButtonRigging.buttonMode = true;
                broadsideFireButtonRigging.useHandCursor = true;
                broadsideFireButtonRigging.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireButtonHandler);
                broadsideFireButtonRigging.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, broadsideButtonRollOverHandler);
                broadsideFireButtonRigging.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, broadsideButtonRollOutHandler);

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(broadsideFireButtonRigging);

                var broadsideCancelButton: Broadside_Confirm_Btn_Cancel = new Broadside_Confirm_Btn_Cancel();
                broadsideCancelButton.gotoAndStop('default');

                broadsideCancelButton.x = 12;
                broadsideCancelButton.y = 372;

                broadsideCancelButton.name = "broadsideCancelButton";
                broadsideCancelButton.buttonMode = true;
                broadsideCancelButton.useHandCursor = true;
                broadsideCancelButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cancelButtonHandler);
                broadsideCancelButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, broadsideButtonRollOverHandler);
                broadsideCancelButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, broadsideButtonRollOutHandler);

                broadsideConfirmDialog.addChild(broadsideCancelButton);
            }
        }

        function createBroadsideResultsDialog() {

            //left offset for damage squares
            const BROADSIDE_RESULTS_LEFT_OFFSET = 150;
            const INFO_SQUARE_SIZE = 13;

            ////remove the broadside confirm dialog
            //if (broadsideConfirmDialog.parent) {

            //  broadsideConfirmDialog.parent.removeChild(broadsideConfirmDialog);
            //}

            //instance broadside results dialog
            broadsideResultsDialog = new Broadside_Results_Dialog();

            broadsideResultsDialog.x = 430;
            broadsideResultsDialog.y = 117;

            addChild(broadsideResultsDialog);

            //firing and target ship name fields
            broadsideResultsDialog.addChild(textBroadsideShipNameFire);
            broadsideResultsDialog.addChild(textBroadsideShipNameTarget);

            //initial and final hit table fields
            textBroadsideHitTableFormat.size = 28;

            var textBroadsideResultsHitTable: TextField = new TextField();
            textBroadsideResultsHitTable.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideHitTableFormat;

            textBroadsideResultsHitTable.width = 80;
            textBroadsideResultsHitTable.height = 30;
            textBroadsideResultsHitTable.x = 90;
            textBroadsideResultsHitTable.y = 192;
            textBroadsideResultsHitTable.embedFonts = true;
            textBroadsideResultsHitTable.textColor = 0xFFCC00;

            textBroadsideResultsHitTable.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + targetObj.hitTable + "</p>";

            broadsideResultsDialog.addChild(textBroadsideResultsHitTable);

            var textBroadsideResultsDieRoll: TextField = new TextField();
            textBroadsideResultsDieRoll.defaultTextFormat = textBroadsideHitTableFormat;

            textBroadsideResultsDieRoll.width = 80;
            textBroadsideResultsDieRoll.height = 30;
            textBroadsideResultsDieRoll.x = 192;
            textBroadsideResultsDieRoll.y = 192;
            textBroadsideResultsDieRoll.embedFonts = true;
            textBroadsideResultsDieRoll.textColor = 0xFFCC00;

            textBroadsideResultsDieRoll.htmlText = "<p align='left'>" + diceRoll + "</p>";

            broadsideResultsDialog.addChild(textBroadsideResultsDieRoll);

            //add red X squares for ship's hull damage
            for (var i: int = 0; i < damageObj.initialDamageHull; i++) {

                var xSquareHull = new Ship_Info_SquareX();
                xSquareHull.x = (i * INFO_SQUARE_SIZE) + BROADSIDE_RESULTS_LEFT_OFFSET;
                xSquareHull.y = 254;
                broadsideResultsDialog.addChild(xSquareHull);
            }

            //add red X squares for ship's gun damage
            for (var i: int = 0; i < damageObj.initialDamageGun; i++) {

                var xSquareGun = new Ship_Info_SquareX();
                xSquareGun.x = (i * INFO_SQUARE_SIZE) + BROADSIDE_RESULTS_LEFT_OFFSET;
                xSquareGun.y = 280;
                broadsideResultsDialog.addChild(xSquareGun);
            }

            //add red X squares for ship's rigging damage
            for (var i: int = 0; i < damageObj.initialDamageRigging; i++) {

                var xSquareRigging = new Ship_Info_SquareX();
                xSquareRigging.x = (i * INFO_SQUARE_SIZE) + BROADSIDE_RESULTS_LEFT_OFFSET;
                xSquareRigging.y = 306;
                broadsideResultsDialog.addChild(xSquareRigging);
            }

            //add red X squares for ship's crew damage
            for (var i: int = 0; i < damageObj.initialDamageCrew; i++) {

                var xSquareCrew = new Ship_Info_SquareX();
                xSquareCrew.x = (i * INFO_SQUARE_SIZE) + BROADSIDE_RESULTS_LEFT_OFFSET;
                xSquareCrew.y = 332;
                broadsideResultsDialog.addChild(xSquareCrew);
            }

            var broadsideResultsCloseButton: WSIM_Broadside_Results_Button_Close = new WSIM_Broadside_Results_Button_Close();
            broadsideResultsCloseButton.gotoAndStop('default');

            broadsideResultsCloseButton.x = 111;
            broadsideResultsCloseButton.y = 372;

            broadsideResultsCloseButton.name = "broadsideResultsCloseButton";
            broadsideResultsCloseButton.buttonMode = true;
            broadsideResultsCloseButton.useHandCursor = true;
            broadsideResultsCloseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cancelButtonHandler);
            broadsideResultsCloseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, broadsideButtonRollOverHandler);
            broadsideResultsCloseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, broadsideButtonRollOutHandler);

            broadsideResultsDialog.addChild(broadsideResultsCloseButton);
        }

        //broadside confirm fire button event handler, initiates calculation and application of damage to target ship
        function fireButtonHandler(e: Event) {

            //extra insurance we don't shoot when we shouldn't be able to
            if ((targetObj.firingShip.loadedRight && targetObj.targetStarboard) || (targetObj.firingShip.loadedLeft && !targetObj.targetStarboard)) {

                var broadsideSound: Sound = new Sound_Broadside();
                broadsideSound.play();

                //calculate damage to target ship, decide if this broadside targeted at hull or rigging
                if ("broadsideFireButtonHull" == e.target.name) {

                    //1 hull, 2 rigging
                    targetObj.targetArea = 1;
                    calcGunDamage(1);
                } 

                else {
                    //target is rigging
                    targetObj.targetArea = 2;
                    calcGunDamage(2);
                }
            }
        }

        //broadside confirm cancel button, clear map
        function cancelButtonHandler(e: Event) {

            clearGameMap(e.target);
        }

        //broadside confirm fire button rollover handler
        function broadsideButtonRollOverHandler(e: Event) {

            e.target.gotoAndStop('hover');
        }

        //broadside confirm fire button rollover handler
        function broadsideButtonRollOutHandler(e: Event) {

            e.target.gotoAndStop('default');
        }
```

**Edit 6/10, apparently my reputation is enough now that I can add more screenshots. Have added the previously-missing Broadside Results phase**

Comment: I don't see a way to attach the view without using the answer function. I think the two that are attached are the critical ones. If someone has to see that missing dialog, I'll go ahead and use Answer.

Comment: Remember, anything you should do with the display object, you can use display object tree to determine where to `removeChild()` from. Basically, if you want an entire object to get removed, `this.parent.removeChild(this)` helps 100%.

Comment: Should have mentioned I already tried that as well, turning the straight removeChild(broadsideConfirmDialog) lines into broadsideConfirmDialog.parent.removeChild(broadsideConfirmDialog) and it made no difference.

Comment: Are you in a position to upload your project anywhere?

Comment: For obvious reasons would rather not, but not so stuck on that that I won't do it if it's required to find a solution. I'm going to poke at it again this evening, If I'm still stuck and no one has a workable suggestion I will consider making whole thing available. It's around 15k lines or so now.

Comment: Question: are you using any setChildIndex? Especially for this element that is not responding?  I would love to see what happens if you replace all of your setChildIndex calls to addChild (again, it's kind of a hack, but you may be dealing with a known as3 bug, so this is at least a light weight workaround). See your other question I was working on for some links I've added that go into more depth on this.

Comment: Had missed this comment Neal, but as you see it was me shooting myself. However I continue to have problems with setChildIndex, just not working for me reliably at all. For example I have grid labels (column-row) I can turn on that are children of the ocean, as are the ships. The labels are set to index 1. All of the ships are also children of the ocean and are set to index 2. I have logging in front of me that says that all of the grid labels (textfields) are at index 1, and all ships at index 2 (using getChildIndex). And yet the grid labels are displaying on top of the ships.

Answer (score 1):

I was right the first time, it was indeed a separate instance of that dialog. When I finally sat down to look at this again last night I saw in my logging that there was a log section doubled that shouldn't execute twice. And that's the function that calls for the creation of the Broadside Confirm dialog.

Tracing back, to correct an edge case where enemy ships were selectable when they weren't valid targets, I added an isValidTarget() check in the ship selection function and that ended up with the ghost dialog since isValidTarget calls the Broadside Confirm dialog if the target is valid. I fixed it by adding a mode check to isValidTarget that tells it whether we intend to shoot here or are just checking on target status, which really should have been part of that logic to start with.

One question remains where advice would be much appreciated if someone know, and that is **how do we detect multiple instances of a class/dialog like this in the debugger**? I spent a good 30 minutes in the debugger trying to figure out whether it was a second instance before I posted this, and saw nothing but a single BroadsideConfirmDialog variable, or at least I think so, it gets confusing in the scope chain.

Comment: IIRC there's a class instance counter in FlashDevelop's debugger, search for it in yours. Also, this case might be the clue to your other problem with "empty" ship, something was created twice too.

Comment: Thanks Vesper, will take a look.